# Parsimony in Box -Jenkins model

Tags: box-jenkins

Book of Enders says:

```
A parsimonious model fits the data well without incorporating any needless coefficients.
```

I am confused with this tradeoff, coefficients versus degrees of freedom.

Box and Jenkins argue that
parsimonious models produce better forecasts than overparameterized models.

How do we know that model is overparametrized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a model with a non-significant coefficient that is one example of an over-parameterized model A second a perhaps more prevalent case due to inadequate AIC/BIC model identification procedures is more subtle.

Consider the case where y(t)=a(t) and you inadvertently difference y and obtain
 [1-B]y(t)=[1-theta1*B]a(t) with theta1 = 1.0 . Checking the roots of the polynomial would/should suggest the need for cancellation/simplification/over-parameterization but this is not routinely available in the plain vanilla versions of ARIMA software. It can often be detected by developing the psi weights (pure ma form) where older errors appear to be more important than recent errors .

Comment: (1) Significance and over-parameterization are not so easily equated.  In particular, many models that incorporate categorical variables have a few "non-significant coefficients" for some values of the categories. (2) How do your remaining remarks address the question of determining when a model might have too many parameters?

Comment: Lack of significance can suggest an unnecessary coefficient or an error process that may be inflated by anomalies thus downwards biasing the t tests. My second point was to the impact of self-cancelling parameterization on BOTH  sides of the equation

Comment: I don't disagree, but your post goes beyond this.  It flatly asserts that a non-significant coefficient implies over-parameterization.  At best, that is misleading.

Comment: To use your example where categorical variables have 1 or more non-significant coefficients  .. couldn't that be rectified by reducing the # of categories ? otherwise you are right ..so perhaps my reflections require a non-categorical variable